# Show 'MULTIPLE_VALUES' instead of LISTAGG if there are > 1 records after GROUP BY

Tags: sql, h2

Imagine a table below:
[image: table1]

I want to get the total population in each country but also I'd like to see the name of a city if that city is the only city in the country.

I could run something like

```
select 
  min(Country), 
  listagg(City) within group as City, 
  sum(Population) as Population
from table1
  group by Country
```

but what i want is ('MULTIPLE' is just an example of text I'd like to see instead of the list of cities)
[image]

How can I do that?

I haven't been able to find any solution and my only idea is to use CASE with COUNT but it won't work

P.S. Sorry for the formatting

Comment: can you please format your question

Comment: Done, sorry for that! I had to replace tables with screenshots
I don't why it didn't work - the preview of my question looks totally fine

Comment: can you try the code below and see if it works ? if it doesn't then please share what you see when you run it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count the cities or compare min and max city:

```
select 
  country, 
  case when min(city) = max(city) then min(city) else 'multiple' as city, 
  sum(population) as population
from cities
group by country
order by country;
```

Comment: thanks! I tried something similar and it didn't work but your solution does what exactly I expected to see

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you won't have same city appearing twice

**CODE 1**

```
WITH list_of_cities_ as (

SELECT
COUNTRY,
city,
count(city)     over (partition by country) AS TOTAL_Cities,
SUM(POPULATION) over (partition by country) AS TOTAL_POPULATION

FROM table_

)

select 
DISTINCT
country,
case when TOTAL_Cities > 1 THEN 'Multiple' Else city end as city,
TOTAL_POPULATION

from list_of_cities_
```

**CODE 2**

IF you are interested in getting the list of all cities, instead of keyword
"Multiple"

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=68efe08ab72ef63afa5813925e7f99e0

```
SELECT
COUNTRY,
STRING_AGG(City,',') as LIST_OF_CITIES,
SUM(POPULATION) AS TOTAL_POPULATION
FROM table_
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Yep, but the outer join and the `DISTINCT` are still superfluous in your original query. You select a city from table_. That city row has a country. And you join the country's city-list-and-population row to the city row. Why do you outer join that country? How could that country not exist in list_of_cities_? And if you join that city's country to the city, how can that result in duplicates?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You will understand if you run this code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=5ce911d59bb1f01491c9b7d27cfa7889 as you can see from fiddle, the country will produce duplicates hence distinct is necessary

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what are your thoughts on the fiddle ? also would appreciate if you can unmark the not useful button as the answer is fine

Comment: Okay, sorry, I didn't see that you didn't select the city. You joined the city table only to remove its content again from your query. So, yes, `DISTINCT` was necessary, because you had a quirky query. I suggest you use this rule of thumb: If you `SELECT DISTINCT` it is very likely you are fighting an unnecessarily large intermediate result you have created yourself in the query. `SELECT DISTINCT` is very, very often an indicator for a badly written query. So, look at the query were the duplicates stem from. Then rewrite the query in order not to produce them in the first place.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you for the feedback much appreciate :) yes one way could be to use rank() , see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2f41f6d8fa43a2f558a256596760c065 but your solution is much shorter.

Comment: No, don't use rank or row_number or any analytic function. The problem is: the CTE alone already gets the result. You'd be done. But then you join with the original table for no apparent reason, thus producing duplicate countries. Then you used `DISTINCT` which was awkward enough, but now you are even numbering the rows first in order to get the distinct countries. That's worse. I suggest you delete your answer. It really is not useful.

Comment: At least more than before. Still, in your first query you are using analytic functions to get country aggregates for each city only to boil it down to countries then. Why make the DBMS get the same aggregation over and over and then dismiss them again with `DISTINCT`? If you want to aggregate then use the normal aggregate functions as in your second query. Don't use their analytic counterparts (with `OVER`) plus `DISTINCT`. Keep your queries as simple as possible.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner even if i use the normal ```GROUP BY```  I would still need to create another query where I will join the groupy results just to get the city name in my select statement which would again be a bad approach, unless I use the same logic as you did where I can do ```case when count(city) > 1 then 'Multiple' else min(city) end as City``` So your solution is good